# Do we have $\mathcal O_X(1)(X)=S_1$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, graded-rings, graded-modules

If $S$ is a graded ring which is generated by $S_1$ as an $S_0$-algebra and $X=\operatorname{Proj}S$, do we have $\mathcal O_X(1)(X)=S_1$?

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ is a polynomial ring this is Hartshorne Prop II.5.13.

If $S$ is not a polynomial ring then this is not generally true. Exercise 5.14 provides a counterexample.